# Can Matteo Spinelli's iScroll wrap horizontally?

Tags: iscroll

I'd like to make this kind of carousel wrap around so the content cycles:
http://lab.cubiq.org/iscroll5/demos/carousel

Did I miss an important reference to this function? Here is the documentation: http://iscrolljs.com

Answer (score 0):

you can easily scroll Horizontally using the `scrollX` option:

```js
var myScroll = new IScroll('#wrapper', {scrollX: true, scrollY: false});
```

Comment: You may have confused `wrap` with `scroll`. What I'm looking for is akin to [Flickity.JS'](http://flickity.metafizzy.co/) wrapAround. Here's an example:
http://codepen.io/desandro/pen/myXdej